# Function of quantile function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, cumulative-distribution-functions, quantile, quantile-function

I stumbled across this Theorem in a paper, but I am not able to obtain its reference or solve it. Please help. 
Let $X_1, ..., X_n$ be independent random variables with CDF $\Phi_1,...,\Phi_n$ (which are continuous and strictly increasing), then $X = f(X_1,...,X_n)$, where $f$ is strictly increasing, is a random variable with inverse CDF
$$
\Phi^{-1}(\alpha) = f(\Phi_1^{-1}(\alpha),...,\Phi_n^{-1}(\alpha)).
$$
I thought it would be simple if we use copula, but it works with joint and marginal CDF, here we have quantile function.

Comment: Can you please tell what $f$ strictly increasing means here?

Comment: As stated, this is false, e.g. if $X_1, X_2$ are independent $N(0, 1)$, then $X = X_1 + X_2 \sim N(0, 2)$; for the result to be true, we would need $X \sim N(0, 4)$.

Comment: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8424120&tag=1

Comment: @Adam This is as stated in Theorem 1 of attached paper.

Comment: @Will I think f is strictly increasing if w1<w1 then f(w1)<f(w2). If w1 and w2 are vectors, then at least one component has strict inequality. This is what is meant.

Comment: The paper is wrong. @Cherryblossoms

Comment: @Adam 'for the result to be true, we would need X∼N(0,4)', could you please elaborate this? I would be really grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is false. If $X_1, X_2$ are independent $N(0, 1)$, then their sum $X = X_1 + X_2 \sim N(0, 2)$, with quantile function
$\Phi^{-1}(\alpha) = \sqrt{2}\Phi_1^{-1}(\alpha)$. However, the result you have states that
$$\Phi^{-1}(\alpha) = \Phi_1^{-1}(\alpha) + \Phi_2^{-1}(\alpha) = 2\Phi_1^{-1}(\alpha),$$
which could only be true if $X \sim N(0, 4)$.